# Send-MailMessage based on Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql, powershell-4.0

I am trying to sending email to submittedby users based on below conditions :

1. UserCountry = "Yes" and UserTeamInTheList = "No" → send MailMessage1
2. UserCountry = "No" and UserTeamInTheList = "No" → send MailMessage2

**NOTE :** Also my body of email is in Chinese that doesn't reflect in email. Please help. I get only ?????? in email instead of original message.

Below is the output of the query I am using:

```
$Q  = "Select * from Query"
$cr = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server1 -Database DB1 -Query $Q |
      select FileId,SubmittedBy,UserCountry,UserTeamIsInTheList |
      ft -AutoSize
$cr
```

Now based on the above output and above conditions, I am using below code (I am trying it and it is wrong code of course):

```
$Q  = "Select * from Query"
$cr = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server1 -Database DB1 -Query $Q |
      select FileId,SubmittedBy,UserCountry,UserTeamIsInTheList |
      ft -AutoSize
$cr

foreach ($i in $cr) {
    if (UserCountry -eq "Yes" -and UserTeamIsInTheList -eq "No") {
        Send-MailMessage -To ("SubmittedBy" (*User In the Output above who submitted this file*) -CC “abc@xyz.com” -From “xyz@abc.com" -SMTPServer acb.newbie.co  -Subject “Testing” -Body “MailMessage1”
    } elseif {
        if (UserCountry -eq "No" -and UserTeamIsInTheList -eq "No") {
            Send-MailMessage -To ("SubmittedBy" (*User In the Output above who submitted this file*) -CC “abc@xyz.com” -From “xyz@abc.com" -SMTPServer acb.newbie.co  -Subject “Testing” -Body “MailMessage2”
        } else {
            'Exit'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using `elseif` requires a condition. instead, you used it like a simple `else` statement and put an `if` condition inside its body. That is the only thing logically wrong with the script. Otherwise everything will work as you expected. I would imagine the script would throw that error when you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code, but most significantly is where you populate the `$CR` variable at the top. You've put `| FT` on the end of this which changes the object type to something that then can't be reused further down in the script. You can still output this variable with `Format-Table` you just need to do so separately.

Overall, I suggest you do something like this:

```
$Q = "Select * from Query"
$CR = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server1 -Database DB1 -Query $Q | Select FileId,SubmittedBy,UserCountry,UserTeamIsInTheList
$CR | FT -AutoSize

$MailSettings = @{
    CC = 'abc@xyz.com'
    From = 'xyz@abc.com'
    SMTPServer = 'acb.newbie.co'
    Subject = 'Testing'
}

$Group1 = $CR | Where ($_.UserCountry -eq 'Yes' -and $_.UserTeamIsInTheList -eq 'No') | Select -ExpandProperty SubmittedBy
Send-MailMessage @MailSettings -To $Group1 -Body 'MailMessage1'

$Group2 = $CR | Where ($_.UserCountry -eq 'No' -and $_.UserTeamIsInTheList -eq 'No') | Select -ExpandProperty SubmittedBy
Send-MailMessage @MailSettings -To $Group2 -Body 'MailMessage2'
```

You shouldn't need the `ForEach` loop because instead you can use `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the results based on your criteria and then return just the `SubmittedBy` property. Then because `Send-MailMessage` accepts array input for the `-To` parameter you can just feed this list in to that property. If you don't want each recipient to see the others, you could use `-BCC` instead, or do a `ForEach` to do them individually (but beware you can hit limits when trying to send large numbers of individual emails).

Further I've used Splatting and a hashtable of the settings that are the same for both `Send-MailMessage` commands so we can reuse them without having to duplicate.

Comment: I did some error because of $Group1 and $Group2 and I posted the error in the question . Please see if you can help me. I remaned it as $Group1 --> $submittedby . Also the body of mail is in Chinese language and when I send email I am getting only ????????? instead of Chinese . Can you please hint me on it too.

Comment: For the Chinese issue, add -Encoding UTF8 to Send-MailMessage

Comment: Thanks mark language issue is fixed . But the - To is NULL. the Group1 or Group2 users are not reflecting in email . Thanks for your time  , please hint me on this. But I am getting emails correctlt only the Submitted by condition is wrong.

Comment: Does your submittedby field contain email addresses? Seems like it doesn't.

Comment: Oh...i will join the email of submittedby user ..as of now it shows only displayname ... will try it . Thanks @Mark.